# Can someone help me with the 'maximum 54.0, Java 10' error when building my Unity Android game with Admob integration?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, admob, game-development

Unity Android failed build

error:
java.io.IOException: Can't read [/Users/user/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/aa91abc22c3608da7062f69537a62ac6/googlemobileads-native-unity-runtime.jar(;;;;;;;**.class)] (Can't process class [com/google/unity/ads/UnityAdLoader$1.class] (Unsupported version number [55.0] (maximum 54.0, Java 10))) See the Console for details.

So I tried to resolve the problem via YouTube and all it says is that I need to uncheck and recheck the JDK and go to Assets-> Android resolver-> Force Resolve.

Also I tried to change Target API to 32 but didn't work for me.

Sorry if the question is easy but Im a new in unity game development.

Unity version 2021.3.15f1